# How to set variable from git command output using windows cmd/batch

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, atlassian-sourcetree

I have trouble "forwarding" an output to a variable.
I'm using Atlassian SourceTree with my GIT versioning. There I want to create a custom action, with which I can easily create a zip file of all modified files of one commit. The created file should have a formatted date of the commit time in the filename as *`update-<YYYYmmdd>T<hhMM>.zip`*.

My working batch-file so far *(line numbers for later reference)*:

```
1:  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
2:  set output=
3:  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %1^^') do ( set output=!output! "%%a" )
4:  set hours=
5:  git show -s --format=%%ci %1 > tmptmptmp & set /p hours= < tmptmptmp & del tmptmptmp
6:  set hours=%hours:~0,4%%hours:~5,2%%hours:~8,2%T%hours:~11,2%%hours:~14,2%
7:  git archive -o update-%hours%.zip HEAD %output%
8:  endlocal
```

I'm having trouble to rewrite line 5 (hours-line) to avoid creating a temporary file.
If I do the same as in line 3 (output-line) like:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show -s --format=%%ci %1^^') do ( set hours=!hours! "%%a" )
```

I get the following error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument '%ci': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   `git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]`

I assume this has something to do with the needed *`%ci`* parameter (for formatting the output).

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: try with %c.Not sure if in this case the % should be escaped.

Comment: But *`%c`* ist not a valid parameter for `--format`. `git show -s --format=%ci <commit-id>` returns an iso formatted (I know, not strict) date string of the commits timestamp. Your suggenstion only returns "%c" if used in git bash.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why do you add trailing `^` *caret* (a *circumflex accent*) over the same command used in line 5 `git show -s --format=%%ci %1`.

However, the `=` *equals sign* in `--format=%%ci` should be escaped as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show -s --format^=%%ci %1^^') do set hours=!hours! "%%a"
```

**A proof sample**:

```
==>type 29803777.bat

IF NOT [%1]==[] dir /B %1=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('IF NOT [%1]==[] dir /B %1=') do @echo "%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('IF NOT [%1]^=^=[] dir /B %1^=') do @echo "%%a"

==>29803777.bat x

==>IF NOT [x] == [] dir /B x=
x.txt

==>for /F "delims=" %a in ('IF NOT [x] [] dir /B x ') do @echo "%a"
[] was unexpected at this time.

==>for /F "delims=" %a in ('IF NOT [x]==[] dir /B x=') do @echo "%a"
"x.txt"

==>
```